# How can I git pull on the server optimally?

Tags: git, git-pull

It's two days I'm trying to pull my project (which is on git) on my server. My server has 1GB ram and uses Ubuntu OS. *(usually 200mb of RAM is used by other processes)*.

When I run `git pull origin master` on the server, It throws this:

> fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 533517295 bytes)
>
> fatal: index-pack failed

[image]

Also here is the result of `nano .git/config`:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    packedGitLimit = 512m
    packedGitWindowSize = 512m

[remote "origin"]
    url = https://***@bitbucket.org/***/***.g$
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

[pack]
  threads = 1
  deltaCacheSize = 512m
  packSizeLimit = 512m
  windowMemory = 512m
```

Honestly I cannot get more RAM for my server. Any idea how can I pull my project on the server?

Noted that in reality there are real names instead of `***`.

Comment: What version of git are you using?

Comment: `My server has 1GB ram` ... is your server 10-15 years old?  Most people's _laptops_ are running 8GB or more, certainly for devs and other tech minded folks.  Get more RAM in your server if possible.

Comment: COuld you run `git fsck` on the server? Just to double check the repo doesn't contain corrupted objects that could make git use a large amount of memory

Comment: @DaveShaw `git version 2.7.4`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I know 1GB ram makes it a weak server, but sadly I cannot increase it now.

Comment: @Ferrybig I returned: `notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch (master) .. Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done. .. notice: No default references`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit the amount of memory used during a fetch operation (`git pull` uses `git fetch`), you can use the [`--depth`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#git-pull---depthltdepthgt) flag.

Just run `git pull --depth=10` and increase to number to fetch more and more history (or decrease it if you also run out of memory). Once you have enough objects loaded in history, you can request the remainder object using `git fetch --unshallow`

The downside of pulling with depth is the fact that your repository will take more space on disk, as it also has to account for the multiple states of the repo

Comment: `git pull --depth=10` had the same error, but I did it by `git pull --depth=1`. Thank you.

Comment: ok, now when I run `git fetch --unshallow`, it still throws I also run out of memory. Is executing this command mandatory?

Comment: Only when you want to see the full history, if you want to serve your website to the world (I assume that is your goal, since you are in the /var/www/html directory) it is not needed. You could also run `git pull` multiple times, increasing the value for depth by 1 every time

Comment: You know, it's the server. So I always want to have the last commit in the server. I don't care about the history.